# Getting Null Value While passing data from one app to another-phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Currently i am passing data from one application to another application in phonegap

below is code how i am passing data in form of URL

```
  window.plugins.webintent.sendBroadcast({
                        action: 'io.cordova.example.myapp',
                        extras: {
                            'option': URLDATA
                        }
                        //extras: extras
                    }, function () {
                        alert("success in send broadcast");
                    }, function () {
                        alert("eroor in send broadcast");
                    });
```

Here URLDATA is getting value,

Now on another app i am trying to get value as below

```
window.plugins.webintent.getExtra(window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_TEXT,
function(url) {
    // url is the value of EXTRA_TEXT
}, function() {
    // There was no extra supplied.
}
```

);

here i am able to go to true condition that proves data is coming and function goes to true condition, but i am getting null value while trying to print url

currently i am following this example

https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent

If any one get the idea than let me know

Thanks

Comment: Save the data in your localStorage which you are trying to send

Comment: @Anilkumar is it possible to transfer data from one app to another storing it on local storage?

Comment: Am also not sure just try it once .. i think it will work

Comment: @Anilkumar how will it work? show me some code snap

Comment: OK wait I will try and let you

Comment: It is showing undefined @Aamirkhan

Comment: @Anilkumar so what's the problem? can you show me code?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use "getIntent()" function , and you will get all the intent.

in your case :

```
this.webIntent.getIntent().then((intent) => {
    let intentExtras = intent.extras;
    if (intentExtras == null) {
        let intentExtras = "No extras in intent";
        alert(' Extras: ' + JSON.stringify(intentExtras));           
    }

}, function () {
    alert("Error while getting intent ");
});
```

the result will be something like this :

extras: {'option': URLDATA}